# Trying to recreate Google homepage (HTML/CSS), Can't get footer to stay at bottom

Tags: html, css

Keep getting this (Red is the footer bar) Any advice on getting rid of it? Saw some code online to keep footer at bottom, tried it but it keeps appearing at the middle of the screen. This is for a project trying to copy the look of Google (no need for functioning search). First time attempting something like this, a bit lost.

The Red is the footer (covering the search bar)

[image: screenshot]

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div id="trio">
            <div class="triple" id="You">
                <a href="google.com">+You</a>
            </div>
            <div class="triple" id="Gmail">
                <a href="gmail.com">Gmail</a>
            </div>
            <div class="triple" id="Images">
                <a href="google.com">Images</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
        <div id="search">
            <input class="searchbar" type="text" maxlength="2048" value="Say &quot;Ok Google&quot;">
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <input id="googlesearch" value="Google Search"type="submit"> 
            <input id="secondbutton" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" type="submit"> 
        </div>
        <div id="footer">   
        <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
img {
display:block;
width:269px;
height:95px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 80px;
padding-top: 112px;
}

.triple {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right:0;
}
#trio a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #404040;
;

}
#trio a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#Gmail, #Images {
padding-left: 15px;
}
#search {
width: 400px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
padding-top:30px;
text-align: right;
}
.searchbar {
margin:auto;
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align: right;
}
#buttons {
height:22;
width:250px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}

#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position: relative;

}

#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color: red;
clear:both;
display:block;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing that in order for the `min-height:100%;` applied to the `#wrapper` to work, you should apply also :

```
body,html{
 height:100%;
}
```

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/KzAfG/303/

Answer (score 0):

This should be an easy starting point for this kind of layout:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using "position:fixed" in your style #footer{}

This works for me.

```
<html>

<head><style>
img {
display:block;
width:269px;
height:95px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 80px;
padding-top: 112px;
}

.triple {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right:0;
}
#trio a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #404040;
;

}
#trio a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#Gmail, #Images {
padding-left: 15px;
}
#search {
width: 400px;
height:28px;
margin:auto;
padding-top:30px;
text-align: right;
}
.searchbar {
margin:auto;
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align: right;
}
#buttons {
height:22;
width:250px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}

#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position: relative;

}

#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color: red;
clear:both;
display:block;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div id="trio">
            <div class="triple" id="You">
                <a href="google.com">+You</a>
            </div>
            <div class="triple" id="Gmail">
                <a href="gmail.com">Gmail</a>
            </div>
            <div class="triple" id="Images">
                <a href="google.com">Images</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
        <div id="search">
            <input class="searchbar" type="text" maxlength="2048" value="Say &quot;Ok Google&quot;">
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <input id="googlesearch" value="Google Search"type="submit"> 
            <input id="secondbutton" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" type="submit"> 
        </div>
        <div id="footer">   
        <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then the footer will stick while you scroll.

Comment: But it will stick to the bottom and seeing the page content I dont think the OP needs to scroll the page.